# Return max repeated item in list

Tags: c#, linq, list, count, max

```
        List<string> prod = new List<string>();
        prod.Add("dfg");
        prod.Add("dfg");
        prod.Add("ojj");
        prod.Add("dfg");
        prod.Add("e");
```

In the above code prod List has item "dfg" repeated thrice(max count)...
I want "dfg" as the output because this item is repeated maximum times.
Can anyone help in this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
string maxRepeated = prod.GroupBy(s => s)
                         .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count())
                         .First().Key;
```

Answer (score 29):

Not the absolutely most efficient, but it works:

```
var maxRepeatedItem = prod.GroupBy(x => x)
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                          .First().Key;
```

This is more efficient:

```
var maxRepeatedItem = prod.GroupBy(x => x)
                          .MaxBy(x => x.Count())
                          .First().Key;
```

but it requires [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s extension `MaxBy`

**EDIT (as per comment) :**

If you want **all** the max repeated elements in case of ties, here's a possible solution:

```
var grouped = prod.ToLookup(x => x);
var maxRepetitions = grouped.Max(x => x.Count());
var maxRepeatedItems = grouped.Where(x => x.Count() == maxRepetitions)
                              .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm afraid this approach would return just the first result in case of ties, i.e. multiple keys having a maximum occurrence count.

Comment: @IvanG: the OP has not specified anything about that, however I added a possible solution...

Comment: @digEmAll can you write also the `min` logic of this?