# Most Ordered Products via Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two POCO's

```
public class Customers
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Orders
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming my Data Service returns a List<Customers> and List<Orders>, how would I use Linq to get the Most ordered products?

I want to return Order.Id, Order.Product, and the Count (as Json from a controller action), so I need to also create a new POCO to hold results. something like the following:

```
public class CustomerOrders
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. (Of topic: class names should almost never be plural)

Comment: this is the way http://stackoverflow.com/q/15184598/4767498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to do the following:

1. Group `List<Order> by Product`
2. Project into `IEnumerable<CustomerOrders>`
3. Order the result by `Count`

So it'd look something like this:

```
(from o in orders
 group o by o.Product into og

 select new CustomerOrders { OrderId = og.First().Id, 
                             Product = og.First().Product,
                             Count = og.Count() }
).OrderBy(r=>r.Count)
```

Although, the `OrderId` doesn't make much sense unless it's a list of `Ids`, since you want to get the most ordered product.

Edit: you're correct, that's the right syntax

Comment: This was having problems with ogg. in the select new clause, so I changed to og. and it seems to work, but I'm curious if the results are still correct?

Comment: @user3583, yes that should be right syntax and result

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You don't need customers list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();
            List<CustomerOrders> customerOrders = new List<CustomerOrders>();

            var productOrders = orders.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Product).ToList();

            foreach (var productOrder in productOrders)
            {
                CustomerOrders newOrder = new CustomerOrders();
                customerOrders.Add(newOrder);
                newOrder.OrderId = productOrder.FirstOrDefault().Id;
                newOrder.Product = productOrder.FirstOrDefault().Product;
                newOrder.Count = productOrder.Count();
            }

        }
    }

    public class Orders
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomerOrders
    {
        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use c# syntax instead of linq:

```
var groupedOrders = orders.GroupBy(o => o.Product);
```

This will return a IGrouping per Group where key is the Product name and the value is an IEnumerable containing all the orders for that product

```
var sortedGroups = groupedOrders.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());`
```

This sorts the groups descending by count of the IEnumerable of orders

```
var projectedOrders = sortedGroups.Select(x => new CustomerOrders(){OrderId = x.First().Id, 
                                                  Product = x.First().Product, 
                                                  Count = x.Count()});
```

Example available here http://rextester.com/LRMW38599