# Get most used byte array in a byte array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I get the most used byte array from another bytearray?
Is there is simple way to do this?

So for example:

the input byte array: 41, 4, 5, 42,4,5,42,4,5,42,2

And then the return: 4, 5, 42

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify with an example input and expected output.

Comment: What is a "most used byte array"?

Comment: the array which occurs the most times in the input.

Comment: do you just want the mode?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the mode?

Comment: Does the "smaller" byte array have a specific length?  Would `4,5` and `5,42` be in your result set too?  What about overlapping arrays?  I think you need to be more specific about what your requirements are.

Comment: `mode` is from math - the value that appears most often in a set of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var grouped = prod.ToLookup(x => x);
var maxRepetitions = grouped.Max(x => x.Count());
var allItemsWithEqualMax = grouped.Where(x => x.Count() == maxRepetitions)
                                  .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Creds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184669/496680

Comment: And then, how do I get the output byte array?

Comment: @DaniëlVerhoef `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToList()`

Comment: Oke, one more question, can I only get bytes if they are in one line, so: 4,4,3,4,4 and then it must return 4,4, and not 4,4,4,4

Comment: @DaniëlVerhoef yeah i'm not doing all of your hw for you