# C# Find most common strings in string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have this one problem. There is a string

```
string [5] names = { "John", "Sam", "Harry", "Sam", "John" }
```

I need to find the most common elements in the array. I tried using :

```
string MostCommon = names.GroupBy(v => v)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First()
    .Key;
```

Unfortunately it only finds one element, f.e., `MostCommon = John`, and in this case I need not only `John`, but `Sam` too. How could I do that? Maybe LINQ is not necessary in this case?

Comment: `.First()` is your problem.  Take off the `.First()`, and you'll have more than one result, but you won't know what the specific counts are with that single LINQ statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return max repeated item in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184598/return-max-repeated-item-in-list)

Comment: No, that duplicate makes what OP wants to avoid, only select the very first max. It doesn´t handle the case of the OP where more than one member may have the max count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done as follows -

```
 var nameGroup = names.GroupBy(x => x);
 var maxCount = nameGroup.Max(g => g.Count());
 var mostCommons = nameGroup.Where(x => x.Count() == maxCount).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 12):

`First` will obviously only select the very first element of your sequence. However you need all groups with an equal number. So select the name and number per group and order *afterwards*. Finally select all those groups having the same count as the very first group.

```
var groups = names.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
int max = groups.First().Count;
var mostCommons = groups.Where(x => x.Count == max);
```

EDIT: You could also use [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Where` in the last statement which will avoid unnecessary comparisons for the last elements in the `groups`-list and stops immediately when the first group was found having less elements than the first one:

```
var mostCommons = groups.TakeWhile(x => x.Count == groups.First().Count);
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient way which executes `groups` query (involving grouping and ordering) a lot of times. At least put `groups.First().Count` into a variable outside the last query, to make the `groups` query execute "only" twice. Still it will be worse than the Amit Hasan approach (and not counting the possible non LINQ solutions), but at least can be considered not so bad.

Comment: That's a very good point about the advantage of `TakeWhile` over `Where`.  For the benefit of future readers I think you should consider adding a snippet using `TakeWhile` and possibly even remove the `Where` code entirely because `TakeWhile` is the better choice.

Comment: @BACON Done so.

Comment: @IvanStoev Done as suggested, however I doubt there is an approach that avoids executing the group-statement twice, even in your cited answer the `namegroup` is iterated twice. We *could* force immediate avaluation using `ToList`, but so far both solutions should perform similar. I tested this with a non-LINQ-approach which will also need two iterations of the original sequence.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Correct. The point was to not execute it N times :) The approach with `Max` + `Where` is better because it's O(N) even with 2 passes. While `OrderByDescending` + `First` is O(N * lg(N)) as you know. `GroupBy` operation is O(N) in both cases, so I'm not counting it.

Answer (score 4):

Combine your first LINQ with another similar linq based on the count of the most common name you found.

```
string MostCommon = names.GroupBy(v => v)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First();

int count = names.Where(x => x == MostCommon).Count();

var mostCommonList = names.GroupBy(v => v)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == count);
```

Comment: This does not compile due to the non-existent `.Key` property on the very last line (plus the additional `=` in assigning `mostCommonList`).  It cannot be assumed that there is only one "most common name", so the result needs to be `IEnumerable<string>` and not `string`.  Therefore, `.Key` needs to be removed (or, less usefully, replaced with `.Select(v => v)`).

Comment: @BACON too many bad copy/pastas, thanks for calling me out.  I fixed the `=` and removed both `.Key` statements.  I think the answer should be fine without the `.Select()` as the `.Where` will return an enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

```
//With Dictionary
//This is more useful if you are looking to interview big companies otherwise use the 
 Linq option which is short and handy

public static int MaxOccurrenceOfWord(string[] words)
    {
        var counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        int occurrences = 0;
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            int count;
            counts.TryGetValue(word, out count);
            count++;
             //Automatically replaces the entry if it exists;
            //no need to use 'Contains'
            counts[word] = count;
        }

        string mostCommonWord = null;
        foreach (var pair in counts)
        {
            if (pair.Value > occurrences)
            {
                occurrences = pair.Value;
                mostCommonWord = pair.Key;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The most common number is {0} and it appears {1} times",
            mostCommonWord, occurrences);

        return occurrences;

    }
```