# LINQ Return max repeated item but sorted in reverse

Tags: c#, linq

I have an string array containing names like:

```
[Alex, Alex, Michael, Michael, Dave, Victor]
```

That I convert to a `List<string>`

Then I need to write a function that returns the max repeated item in the list but should be sorted in descending order, which in this case, Michael.

I have followed the LINQ code stated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184598/return-max-repeated-item-in-list). Which is:

```
string maxRepeated = prod.GroupBy(s => s)
                     .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count())
                     .First().Key;
```

However, code returns Alex instead of Michael.

I tried to add another `OrderByDescending` however it returns Victor.

```
string maxRepeated = prod.GroupBy(s => s)
                     .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count())
                     .OrderByDescending(b => b)
                     .First().Key;
```

I am stuck and don't know what needs to be added to achieve the desired result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a second `OrderByDescending` which ignores the previous order but `ThenByDescending`:

```
string maxRepeated = prod.GroupBy(s => s)
                     .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                     .ThenByDescending(g => g.Key)
                     .First().Key;
```

Comment: This one is almost correct. ThenByDescending(g => g) should be ThenByDescending(g => g.Key).

Comment: You're welcome, it should be the accepted answer now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add a condition after the "GroupBy" to limit it to groups with more than one item. This is basically the equivalent of "Having" in SQL. I think this would do what you want:

```
prod.GroupBy(s => s)
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .Select(group => group.Key)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s)
    .First();
```

Comment: You might wanna change lambda variable name, `group` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: OP hasn't stated that he wants the one that is **not unique** and repeated most, we just know that he wants the string that is repeated most. That could mean it's unqiue. Your query would throw an exception if there is no string repeated.

Comment: It's only considered a keyword when it's used in linq query syntax, so this would compile. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#contextual-keywords