# How can I find the n most common elements?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array:

```
string[] myFruits =
{
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "banana",
    "orange",
    "cherry",
    "cherry",
    "cherry",
    "mango",
    "kiwi",
    "kiwi",
}
```

I want a new collection with the 3 most popular fruits, in order.  In this example, it would be `["cherry", "banana", "kiwi"]`.

I have been looking at Linq, trying to figure out how to use the GroupBy, OrderByDescending, and Count in some sort of combination to get me the desired results, but I have not been even close to successful.

For example:

```
var popularFuits = myFruits.GroupBy(f => f).OrderByDescending(f => f.Count).Take(3);
```

How can I get the most popular n strings from a collection?

Comment: `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: @stuartd Oops.  Nice catch.  Thanks!  But that is not the part I am struggling with.  It is the LINQ logic.  The above example doesn't even compile.  I will actually edit that fix so it doesn't get in the way of the root of my question.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: [Return max repeated item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184598/return-max-repeated-item-in-list).

Comment: @Christian That is similar, but not quite.  hazzik has saved my day though!

Comment: No worries, just wanted to help. Glad that you solved you problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you fruits sorted by popularity and then alphabetically if they're equally popular

```
var popularFuits = myFruits
    .GroupBy(f => f)
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        Name = g.Key, 
        Count = g.Count() 
    })
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.Count)
    .ThenBy(f => f.Name)
    .Take(3);

foreach (var fruit in popularFuits)
    Console.WriteLine($"{fruit.Name} - {fruit.Count}");
```

OUTPUT

> cherry - 3
>   banana - 2
>   kiwi - 2

Comment: `GroupBy` has an overload which allows to transform the group. `.GroupBy(f => f, (key, items) => new { Name = key, Count = items.Count() })`

Comment: @hazzik thanks... a little more succinct.  But probably harder to understand for a newbie.

Answer (score 4):

Your query is almost there.

1. `IGrouping<T>` does not have `.Count` property, so you need to use `.Count()` extension method
2. You need to select the `.Key` of the group.

---

```
var popularFuits = myFruits
    .GroupBy(f => f)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .Take(3) /*.ToList()*/;
```

Comment: Thank you!!  That is exactly what I was trying to do.  What is the .Key?  Will that just always be equal to one distinct value in the grouping?

Comment: @Evorlor, .Key is the thing you group elements by - in your case the value of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sVhf0I)

You can `GroupBy` then `OrderByDescending` the number of items in a group like below.

```
var result = myFruits.GroupBy(p => p)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                    .Take(3);
foreach(var item in result)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Count());
```

**Output**

```
cherry 3
banana 2
kiwi 2
```

Comment: What makes your answer different from the one provided by @hazzik ?

Comment: Just the same idea(I've not read the other answers), different from `explanation` and give example with the corresponding result. Happy coding.